# What types of dungeons can be found on which planets in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

From what I understand, dungeons are distributed according to planet biomes. Which dungeons can be found on which planet type then? For example, I'm pretty sure you can find floran dungeons on jungle worlds, but I would like a definitive list of the rest.

Comment: Keep in mind that since the game is still in early access, a 'definitive list' is a fuzzy concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a quick script to parse `/terrestrial_worlds.config` (or rather the same with C++-style comments stripped), and here's the raw output as of a few days ago (February 3, 2015):

alien:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, avianairship, aviantemple, aviantomb, aviantower, floranhell, floranhuntinggrounds, glitchcastle, glitchsewer, humanbunker, humanprison, scifidungeon

desert:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, apextowerblock, aviantomb, aviantower, avianvillage, floranhuntinggrounds, floranvillagetower, glitchsewer, glitchvillage, humanbunker

forest:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, apextowerblock, aviantomb, aviantower, avianvillage, floranhuntinggrounds, floranvillagetower, glitchsewer, glitchvillage, humanbunker

garden:

> naturalcave

jungle:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, avianairship, aviantemple, aviantomb, aviantower, floranhell, floranhuntinggrounds, glitchcastle, glitchsewer, humanbunker, humanprison, scifidungeon

savannah:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, apextowerblock, aviantomb, aviantower, avianvillage, floranhuntinggrounds, floranvillagetower, glitchsewer, glitchvillage, humanbunker

scorched:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, avianairship, aviantemple, aviantomb, aviantower, floranhell, floranhuntinggrounds, glitchcastle, glitchsewer, humanbunker, humanprison, scifidungeon

snow:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, apextowerblock, aviantomb, aviantower, avianvillage, floranhuntinggrounds, floranvillagetower, glitchsewer, glitchvillage, humanbunker

tundra:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, avianairship, aviantemple, aviantomb, aviantower, floranhell, floranhuntinggrounds, glitchcastle, glitchsewer, humanbunker, humanprison, scifidungeon

volcanic:

> apexresearchlab, apextestchamber, avianairship, aviantemple, aviantomb, aviantower, floranhell, floranhuntinggrounds, glitchcastle, glitchsewer, humanbunker, humanprison, scifidungeon

"garden" is the lush planet type, "savannah" is the arid planet type, "scorched" is the dead planet type, and "tundra" is the snow planet type with the extreme cold warning.

**EDIT:**

Here's the Python 2.x script I used to extract the data. Uses [py-starbound](https://github.com/blixt/py-starbound) and [commentjson](https://commentjson.readthedocs.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

import starbound
import commentjson

with starbound.open_file(sys.argv[1]) as assets:
  tw = commentjson.loads(assets.get('/terrestrial_worlds.config'))

for pt in sorted(tw['planetTypes']):
  if 'dungeons' in tw['planetTypes'][pt]['layers']['surface']:
    print '{}:'.format(pt)
    print ', '.join(sorted(tw['planetTypes'][pt]['layers']['surface']['dungeons']))
    print
```

Just pass it the location of `packed.pak`.

Comment: If you can post the script in a gist or something then we can all help keep the data updated.

Comment: I need to refactor it so that it uses [py-starbound](https://github.com/blixt/py-starbound) and/or [commentjson](https://commentjson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) before it's ready to be posted. As it is, I did a lot of manual preprocessing of the data.